# Angular drag and drop performance

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular7, angular-cdk

I am developping an app using angular 7  in the frontend and i am using angular drag and drop cdk.While dragging the element i have an algorithm which i must execute but unfortunately this algorithm is slowing the drag and drop so is there a way to make this treatment and make the drag and drop faster.By the way the call of the algorithm is in the  dragMove(event) method.

```
dragMove(event: CdkDragMove<Cycle>) {
    this.parentClientRect = event.source.getRootElement().parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.clientRect = event.source.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.leftPosition =
        this.clientRect.left - this.parentClientRect.left - ((this.clientRect.left - this.parentClientRect.left) % ConstantesGda.STEP);
    if (this.leftPosition < 0) {
        this.leftPosition = 0;
    }
    event.source.element.nativeElement.style.transform = `translate3d(${this.leftPosition}px, 0px, 0px)`;
this.callAlgo();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *slowing*? Less responsive?

Comment: slow motion while dragging

Answer (score 0):

If you have an algorithm running that requires some CPU and can freeze the UI, you could divide it in parts and queue it using `setTimeout`. For example, something like this:

```
function heavyProcess(params) {
  for (let i=0;i< 1000; i++) {
     doSomething(params[i]); //needs 0.005 secs
  }
}
```

It would make the browser non-responsive for about 0.005 * 1000 = 5 secs.But it could be refactor to something like:

```
function heavyProcess(params) {
  for (let i = 0; i < someSize; i++) {
     setTimeout(()=>doSomething(params[i]));
  }
}
```

So now you have 1000 small functions queued to be processed and events can be handled in the middle of two of these.